# Regex for removing white space in amount float input field while user type and copy paste

Tags: javascript, html, regex, pattern-matching

I have input field which accept only float numbers eg:10.25 I need regex for following scenario.

Regex should follow below points

1. Should not accept space.
2. Should accept only one dot(.)
3. If user copy and paste amount value like 21 32.44 in input field. It should show 2132.44 value space should be removed.

I have implemented this using regex `"^[\\d.]+$"`, but while copy and paste amount value in input field it's removing all numbers after space.

Ex: 21 32.44 -> it gives only 21

Could someone provide valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var input=require("readline-sync")
var regx= /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/
do{ 
var num= input.question("Input float number please : ");
var m= regx.exec(num.trim().replace(/\s+/g,'')) } while(m==null);
console.log(m[0]);
```

Output test:

```
Input float number please : dsfd fdsa
Input float number please : 4324 543. 543 fds
Input float number please : 432 54.54
43254.54
```

Comment: I cannot add function to execute above statement. Need in regex attribute in input field. <input type="text" regex="/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/" />. Basically one regex code to support all criteria. Regex /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/ this doesn't support call criteria.

Comment: You just can use `prompt()` for `user input` instead of above script's `readline-sync` module which is used for `synchronized user input` in `node.js` like this. `var num= prompt("Input float number please : ");`